# Avoiding data type exceptions - how to simplify this expression

Tags: exception, view, casting, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Data coming from my OLTP into Snowflake is not strongly typed - it is json. Trying to avoid casting exceptions in my snowflake views
I have a numeric field "Loan Amount". which can be NULL, EMPTY (0 length) string, or a Numeric value.

```sql
CAST(
   CASE 
      When LENGTH(attributes:application.loan_amount.value) = 0 THEN 0 
      ELSE IFNULL(attributes:application.loan_amount.value,0) 
   END 
as Number) as loan_amount
```

Is there an easier, more efficient way to code this? I have to repeat it many, many times.

Comment: `TRY_CAST(attributes:application.loan_amount.value AS NUMBER)`

Comment: Function TRY_CAST cannot be used with arguments of types VARIANT and NUMBER

Answer (score 1):

`TRY_TO_DOUBLE` might be helpful in this case

Tried it with

```
with d as (
select parse_json('{"a":1}') v
union all
select parse_json('{"a":0.1}')
union all
select parse_json('{"a":0}')
union all
select parse_json('{"a":""}')
union all
select parse_json('{"b": 10}') 
)
select v:a raw_value, IFNULL(TRY_TO_DOUBLE(v:a::string),0) loan_amount from d
```

The result is

```
RAW_VALUE   LOAN_AMOUNT
1           1
0.1         0.1
0           0
""          0
NULL        0
```

It's a lot less busier than your CASE statement.

Cast for string is necessary because [TRY_TO_DOUBLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_double.html#try-to-double) expects a string input